# Viewing my webrick server @ lvh.me:3000 on a networked windows machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please let me know if there is a better exchange to post this on.

I generally run my rails apps locally when testing them. I use lvh.me to point back to my localhost. I really need to do some testing in IE. I have a windows laptop on my desk, so I'd like to be able to just view the server running on the mac from the windows laptop. Pulling up my IP in the browser the windows lap doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add the port to the IP? Like `http://192.168.1.20:3000/`

Comment: Yes, and it comes up - doesn't like demo.192....

Comment: Do I need to had an entry in the hosts file of the windows machine to map 192.168.1.2 to something better?

Comment: So you are trying to access a subdomain? Pow (http://pow.cx) and xip.io (http://xip.io) can make your life a lot easier.